# Как открыть pcm-устройство в ALSA?

Tags: c++, linux, c, аудио

Задача такая: у меня несколько (переменное число) USB-звуковух. Требуется организовать запись многоканального звука. Надо дать возможность пользователю выбрать записывающие устройства из списка и запустить запись только с этих устройств.

```
int i(0);
char *cardName = new char[32];
snd_ctl_t *sndCtl;
void **hints;
char *name;
сhar *desc;
сhar *io;

while(i >= 0) {
    qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("## int card:") << i;
    snd_card_get_name(i, &cardName);
    qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("## snd_card_get_name:") << cardName;
    snd_card_get_longname(i, &cardName);
    qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("## snd_card_get_longname:") << cardName;
    snd_device_name_hint(i, "pcm", &hints);
    name = snd_device_name_get_hint(*hints, "NAME");
    desc = snd_device_name_get_hint(*hints, "DESC");
    io = snd_device_name_get_hint(*hints, "IOID");
    qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("## name:") << name << "desc: "<< desc << "io:" << io;
    if(snd_card_next(&i) != 0) {
        lastErrorStr = "can't determine sound cards";
        return false;
    }
    qDebug();
}
```

Для открытия в ALSA API есть функция

```
int snd_ctl_open(snd_ctl_t **ctl, const char *name, int mode);
```

Что подставлять в `name`?

Вывод приложения сейчас (пытался открыть по имени `plughw:C,D`):

> "## int card:" 0
>   "## snd_card_get_name:" HDA Intel
>   "## snd_card_get_longname:" HDA Intel at 0x98300000 irq 29
>   "## name:" front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0 desc: HDA Intel, ALC268 Analog 
>   Front speakers io:
>   ALSA lib control.c:882:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL plughw:0,0
>   "## int card:" 1
>   "## snd_card_get_name:" Generic USB Audio Device
>   "## snd_card_get_longname:" Generic USB Audio Device    at             usb-
>   0000:00:1d.7-1.1, full speed
>   "## name:" front:CARD=default,DEV=0 desc: Generic USB Audio Device   , USB Audio
>   Front speakers io:
>   ALSA lib control.c:882:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL plughw:1,0
>   "## int card:" 2
>   "## snd_card_get_name:" Generic USB Audio Device
>   "## snd_card_get_longname:" Generic USB Audio Device    at     usb-  0000:00:1d.7-1.2, full speed
>   "## name:" front:CARD=default_1,DEV=0 desc: Generic USB Audio Device   , USB    > Audio
>   Front speakers io:
>   ALSA lib control.c:882:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL plughw:2,0
>   "## int card:" 3
>   "## snd_card_get_name:" Generic USB Audio Device
>   "## snd_card_get_longname:" Generic USB Audio Device    at usb-0000:00:1d.7-1.3, full speed
>   "## name:" front:CARD=default_2,DEV=0 desc: Generic USB Audio Device   , USB
>   Audio
>   Front speakers io:
>   ALSA lib control.c:882:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL plughw:3,0
>   "## int card:" 4
>   "## snd_card_get_name:" Generic USB Audio Device
>   "## snd_card_get_longname:" Generic USB Audio Device    at usb-0000:00:1d.7-1.4,
>   full speed "## name:" front:CARD=default_3,DEV=0 desc: Generic USB Audio Device   , USB Audio
>   Front speakers io:
>   ALSA lib control.c:882:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL plughw:4,0`\